# What Languages have historically had Purification Movements?

Tags: historical-linguistics, cross-linguistic, greek, sociolinguistics, history

Greek has been notorious for trying to purify the language. People tried to conserve the Attic Dialect which evolved to what is today called *Katharevousa*, which even means purified.

Historically, common citizens used the Koine dialect; while the Palace, education, official documents and even high end Personas used the Attic dialect. It was a state of diglossia for about 2 millenia. Koine's modern form *Demotike* did not achieve an easy and swift victory.

Have there been any similar controversies in other languages over whether or not to maintain a pure form of the language? Would *Real Academia Española*'s activities count as an example?

Comment: Your example (Greek) is not about "purism". It's more a case of a conservative variety that is used alongside a more innovative vernacular. "Purism" is about removing what is perceived as foreign or vulgar, like coining new German words in order to remove French words, or new Turkish words in order to remove Arabic or Persan borrowings.

Comment: As A. Fournet said that is not purism. The case of katharevousa is wrongly described sometimes like a language replacement. None is speaking katharevousa today and even if one tries it sounds rather riddiculous. Greek still contains a considerable number of words from Latin and Turkish.

Comment: @ArnaudFournet The only difference is that Greek did not need to coin new Greek words to replace foreign words. Otherwise it was exactly that an attempt to regress to the pure Attic dialect which had no foreign influences. Demotike and Koine to a lesser extend had the problem that they were not pure. Why is it conservatism to regress to the pure language with no foreign influences but purism to coin new words. Katharevousa means exactly that Purifying.

Comment: @Midas I did not say it was a succesful attempt but for 2 millenia they were trying to go back to the pure original Greek words, grammar, syntax, phonetics, orthography.

Comment: @ George Ntoulos Purism would be to coin words in modern Greek to remove the loanwords from Latin and Turkish. This is purism. What you describe as Katharevousa is the preservation of an archaic (and possibly prestigious) variety alongside a vernacular. This is similar to having Latin and Italian side by side. It makes no sense to claim that Latin is "pure" Italian. Besides, Attic Greek is full of substratic and adstratic words of non-Indo-European origin, so it's completely false to claim that this language has no foreign influences.

Comment: @ArnaudFournet It is certainly not that case that Attic is absolutely pure. But there are people that due to nationalism or obsession with Ancient Athens and Greek History in general that idealise Attic greek and it is certainly has less admixtures than Koine/Demotike. They try to preserve the purity and resist foreign influences not by coining new words but seeking to replace the new words with the classic words.

Comment: @ArnaudFournet And adstratal words in Attic Greek are obvious but substratal? I cannot think of any substrate languages to Greek. Languages that form a substratum. A foundation/basis.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos: Greek has many substratal words. We can presume that those come from Minoan or other languages spoken in Greece during neolithic and early bronze age era.

Comment: @Midas So Neolithic,Cycladic and Minoan. But could one(a modern linguist) identify a Neolithic, Cycladic or Minoan word in the Attic greek? We have gone up to Linear B but Linear A is a tottaly different story. But I need to say that many Nationalists or otherwise people obsessed with conserving the language are obsessed with Attic even it was not absoluttely pure.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos: Since we cannot know what is Minoan or Cycladic etc, it is better to use the label Pre-Greek. Pre-Greek is not specific to Attic or Doric or whatever dialect, it is usually found across all dialects. For Attic specifically, without making it too complicated just look at the toponyms of Attica. It is full of non-IE names.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos: Regarding people preserving their language or being concervative, it is not always a case of nationalism (although in many cases it is). Icelanders are reluctant to loanwords from other languages and instead reuse or invent words in Icelandic to express themselves. By no means are Icelanders or Iceland as a state conservative in the sense of 19th and 20th century nationalism. Far from it.

Comment: @Midas Is preserving ones language not being a purist thought?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos: What is a purist thought? By default, people do preserve their language. They do use terms that feel natural to them. Whenever it feels more convenient they use loans. The difference between Icelandic and other languages that underwent somekind of purification is that Icelanders create icelandic words by default, it is like a tradition. They didn't first loan 200 words and 20 years later got rid of them.

Comment: @Midas I would define Purism as an attempt to intently preserve( purify) the language and rid it of all its influences (impurities).

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos: I think you are thinking of state level attempts. Among people using native words or loans is part of the language evolution. The speakers of a language are not thinking in terms of "purism" as the processes of language evolution are complex.

Comment: @Midas Katharevousa was a blatant attempt to do so. It was even named after its purpose. I am not restricting it to state level attempts but I am restricting it to "exterior" attempts not self-imposed ones. Scholars, Academia, High-end personas. I am certainly not saying that the speakers themself are purists.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos I understand. One attempt that was more successful was the replacement of Ottoman Turkish with old Turkish. Today, Ottoman turkish is kinda hard to understand, depending of course on the level of education of the speaker. O. Turkish had a vast amount of Persian and Arabic words that were replaced in a large scale. Of course, that did not wipe them out completely as still today they remain numerous.

Comment: @Midas Was that replacement though faced with much opposition? How much of a turmoil was there? I am interested in both extent(timely duration and extent in different fields of knowledge par example even Physicians and Medicine as a subject were in favour of Katharevousa) and intensity.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos I don’t think there was much, if any opposition, but let me ask those details to someone who knows and I will get back to you.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos In the case of Turkey, most resistance came from people who didn’t want to adopt the Latin alphabet. Although that reform was much necessary, the Arabic script had a religious status. I guess that made people to put their efforts and energy on that, instead of complaining about word replacements.

Comment: @Midas But my question was about the inverse situation. People resisting and opposing purification.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos: I know and for Turkey that was not the case. The script was more of an issue. There is a famous photo of Mustafa Kemal Ataturk visiting schools and showing kids how to spell with the Latin alphabet.

Comment: @Midas So Kemal Ataturk was not trying to Purify( Unless the replacement of the Arab Script with the Latin Alphabet coincided with the replacement of Ottoman Turking with Old Turkish) he was trying to Modernize. I am indifferent to Modernization in this question. In case that Modernization and Purification coincided was the Purifying attempt( replacing Ottoman Turking with Old Turking) met with much opposition and resistance?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos Your first premise is false. He attempted successfuly both in purifying (the language) and modernizing (the writing). Since language purification occured in parallel with the transition to the Latin alphabet, it did not get much resistance, as people were more disturbed by the replacement of the Arabic script which had religious status.

Comment: @Midas It was not a premise it was the result in itself. The premise was the negation of what you just told me. I did not know that these two run parallel that is the reason I put in parentheses the premise as an hypothesis( I used unless). The replacement of Ottoman Turkish then with Old Turkish not having been met with much opposition and resistance and even being succesful makes it blatantly different from Katharevousa which was met with both opposition and resistance and ultimately failed at large.

Comment: @Midas I am mainly interested in attempts that ultimately failed or had limited success and were met with much opposition and resistance from the academics of the language. In Greece we had the Δημοτικιστές and Manolis Triantafyllides was one of them.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos ok, Turkey’s case was definetely successful. Since you asked me and I promiswd to come back, I did. Maybe, nynorsk (New Norwegian) will have similar fate in a decade or two. Not sure though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In French, a quite recent example would be the [Toubon Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toubon_Law). This law enforces the use of French in all official media, as a way to struggle against the massive use of English language. It followed a quite usual trend by the *Académie Française* of trying to coin French words to replace English neologisms that started by being adopted as-is. This often concerns new technologies, though not always.

The success was limited (and the law was made fun of by being called "loi AllGood") but some words survive. For instance French has *baladeur* which was coined as an almost exact translation of the word *walkman*, which was rendered obsolete by the success of this new word (well, granted, walkmans are now pretty obsolete objects themselves, nowadays). Prior to the law, the academy coined *logiciel* for *software*, which is now a standard.

This trend to "fight" against English language is much stronger in Québec, Canada, since the rest of the country speaks English. They will translate everything. For instance, in France french language, many US movies retain their original name, while the name will be translated in Québec french language. Another recent example, in french, the word *télécharger* used to mean *download* or *upload*, without clear distinction, leading to ambiguities. More and more, in France french language, *télécharger* means only *download* and *uploader* was coined, which is adding the french ending "er" to the english word. In constrast, for *upload*, Québec french language uses *téléverser* which is a portmanteau of *télécharger* and *verser* (to pour).

Comment: I am interested in attempts that ultimately failed or had limited success and were met with much opposition and resistance. As such Toubon Law is an excellent example. But was there any opposition from French academics of the French language( In Greece we had the Δημοτικιστές and Manolis Triantafyllides was one of them) or the opposition was restricted to common people?